# How to do a substring in set variable

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am new to mulesoft

I have a flow variable named `logPrefix` with value `"Id1 - 123 - Id2 - 456"`

I want to use the set-variable component and change the value of this variable to `"Id1 - 123"`.

Note that I don't want to do this `vars.logPrefix[0 to 8]`

I would like to do something cleaner based on finding the index of "Id2" within the string `logPrefix` and using substring on `logPrefix` using this index

If set-variable isn't the best way to do this, let me know that too please

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below approach .

Edit: Based on @aled suggestion I have updated [substringBefore](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-strings-functions-substringbefore) instead of splitBy which will give all elements before "Id2". Since your desired output is before last "-" from above result, I have used [substringBeforeLast](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-strings-functions-substringafterlast) which will get all the elements before "-" . Further [trim](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-trim) will remove extra spaces after "-"

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings
var logPrefix="Id1 - 123 - Id2 - 456"
---
trim(substringBeforeLast((substringBefore(logPrefix,"Id2")),"-"))
```

Output

```
"Id1 - 123"
```

Comment: Instead of `split()` I would suggest `substringBefore()`. I believe it communicates better the intention: `trim(substringBeforeLast(substringBefore(logPrefix, "Id2"), "-"))`